# Facebook meta / share - change provider ("By website.com" text)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

Is it possible to change the provider text for a website article when it gets shared on facebook?
Right now, when someone shares something off one of our websites, there will be the following provider text below the title and description in the sharing dialogue:
"CLIENTDOMAIN.COM | BY COMPANYDOMAIN.COM"

I am wondering if we can somehow either remove the "BY COMPANYDOMAIN.COM" or change it to something else (for instance "BY BLOG AUTHOR").

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Should be the `og:site_name` meta tag that’s responsible for that, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties#standard

Also, depending on which object type you choose, an author/publisher can be explicitly specified as well (although those must point to a Facebook user profile or page), for example for the `article` type, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/#properties

Comment: If I read this correctly, an author for an article can only be a facebook profile? But in any case, I found it. It's just the regular <meta name="author"> that feeds the "By ..." text. Thanks for the hints though, I looked at the source again and saw that the author meta tag is exactly the same as the By text!

Do you want to add that meta tag to your answer? The first half of the provider stems from the og:site_name so that's correct, I'd like to mark yours as the correct answer.